# Javascript map() on a 2D array

Tags: javascript

I would expect `newArray` to be `[4, 2, 5]`, but instead I get 3 copies of that in a 2D array. It doesn't seem to match up with what the `console.log` says. Why?

```js
let myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 6],
  [9, 2, 4, 5, 1]
]

let newArray = myArray.map(function(currentArray){
  this.push(currentArray[3]);
  console.log("this: " + this);
  return this;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: What does console.log says

Comment: `this` in your example is a new array, and since your callback returns that, all elements become references to that array.

Comment: The `.map()` method creates a new array implicitly. All your function has to do is `return currentArray[3];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls its provided `callbackFn` function once for each element in an array and constructs a new array from the results.

In our case, the array we are operating on has 3 elements, so `map` will call the callback 3 times.

You also provided a 2nd argument here, which will be used as `this` when executing `callbackFn`. The value you are passing is a new array.

Let's rewrite your example code with some variables to make things easier to discuss:

```js
const item1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const item2 = [8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 6];
const item3 = [9, 2, 4, 5, 1];

const myArray = [
 item1,
 item2,
 item3,
];

const thisArg = [];

const newArray = myArray.map(function callbackFn(currentArray) {
  this.push(currentArray[3]);
  return this;
}, thisArg);
```

OK, let's step through each iteration of the `callbackFn` call

#### 1) First Iteration

- At the start, some values are:

  - `currentArray` is `item1`
  - `this` is an empty array `[]`
  - The "accumulator" that'll be returned from `map` also initializes as a different empty array `[]`
- So we execute the function, which does

  1. Grabs `item1[3]`, which is `4`
  2. Pushes that onto `this`, which becomes `[4]`
  3. Returns `this`, *which "adds" that* to our accumulator. So our accumulator now looks like `[[4]]`. Remember, our accumulator is an array, and when we return `this`, it adds that item to it.

So far so good? OK, next step:

#### 2) Second Iteration

- At the start of the 2nd iteration, some values are:

  - `currentArray` is `item2`
  - `this` is `[4]`
  - The "accumulator" is `[thisArg]`.
- Notice that the accumulator is just holding a [*reference*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) to the `thisArg`, and not a copy. This is important! Now let's execute the callback

  1. Grabs `item2[3]`, which is `2`
  2. Pushes that onto `this`, which becomes `[4, 2]`
  3. Returns `this`, so our accumulator now is `[thisArg, thisArg]`. It is holding two references to the same array! Since `thisArg` looks like `[4, 2]`, that means that the accumulator looks like `[[4, 2], [4, 2]]`. Remember, those elements aren't two different arrays, they are the **same** array!

The third step should make sense now.

#### 3) Third Iteration

- At the start:

  - `currentArray` is `item3`
  - `this` is `[4, 2]`
  - The "accumulator" is `[thisArg, thisArg]`.
- Execute:

  1. Grabs `item3[3]`, which is `5`
  2. Push that onto `this`, which becomes `[4, 2, 5]`
  3. Returns `this`, so our accumulator now is `[thisArg, thisArg, thisArg]`, which evaluates to `[[4, 2, 5], [4, 2, 5], [4, 2, 5]]`.

And we are done! The accumulator is returned, and `newArray` is set to that value.

To further prove that `newArray` contains 3 references to the same object, you can mutate that object a *fouth* time, and watch how `newArray` changes.

```js
// After your map call...
newArray[0].push(9);

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
// logs "[ [4, 2, 5, 9], [4, 2, 5, 9], [4, 2, 5, 9] ]"
```

> See the documentation on [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and how the iterative methods (like `map`) [work with the optional `thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#iterative_methods) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Seems an easy task, trying to use `this` as the result array in `map` doesn't make sense, `this` is usually the array being mapped. But in my case I use an arrow function for mapping so `this` inside it references the outer scope's `this`.

```js
const myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 6],
  [9, 2, 4, 5, 1]
];

const mapIndex = (arr, idx) => arr.map(arr => arr[idx]);

console.log(mapIndex(myArray, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution, `.map()` already creates a new array for you, so just return the the 4th element of each array like this

```js
let myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 6],
  [9, 2, 4, 5, 1]
]

let newArray = myArray.map(x => { return x[3]; });

console.log(newArray);
```

or to make it shorter

```
let newArray = myArray.map(x => x[3] );
```

Answer (score 0):

A more minimal form of this is:

```
myArray.map(a => a[3])
```

Where that just selects the index 3 element from each of the sub-arrays.

Whenever you see a pattern like `x = [ ]` and later `x.push(...)` without conditions, you typically have code that can be better expressed as `x = y.map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

because you're using  `this` inside the `map()` function without providing an array as the second argument. In this case, `map()` defaults to using an empty array. and when `this` is referenced, it actually points to the default empty array. and in each iteration, the empty array gets populated with the fourth element of each subarray and is returned. This leads to the generation of three arrays, each containing the assigned values, resulting in the unexpected output.

here's the correct version of the code

```
let myArray = [
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 6],
 [9, 2, 4, 5, 1]
];

let newArray = myArray.map(function(currentArray){
  return currentArray[3];
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using using a simple for loop.

```
let myArray = [
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 6],
     [9, 2, 4, 5, 1]
    ];

let flattenedArr = [];
let result = [];

for(let rows = 0; rows < myArray.length; rows++){
    flattenedArr = myArray[rows]
    result.push(flattenedArr[3])
}
    
console.log(result)
```